# Как изменить цвет у JScrollBar?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Как изменить цвет у вешки разбивки в JSplitPane и у JScrollBar в JScrollPane?

`setBackground()` самой собой пробовал.

Answer (score 1):

В Swing рисование компонента возложено на [UI-делегатов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html), в случае с используемым по-умолчанию Metal - это содержимое пакета `javax.swing.plaf.metal`: `MetalSplitPaneUI` и `MetalScrollBarUI` соответственно. Документировано все [так себе](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/metal/package-summary.html), поэтому идите сразу в код.

У `ScrollBar` есть несколько свойств, вроде `"ScrollBar.gradient"` и `"ScrollBar.thumb"`, `SplitPane` рисуется базовыми цветами темы. Свойства программно задаются через `UIManager.put`, как-то так:

```
    UIManager.put( "ScrollBar.thumb", Color.GRAY );
    UIManager.put( "ScrollBar.gradient", Arrays.asList(0.0, 1.0, new ColorUIResource( Color.GREEN ), new ColorUIResource( Color.GREEN ), new ColorUIResource( Color.BLUE )) );
```

Можно подойти к вопросу серьезно, написать собственный делегат (унаследовав от стандартного) и переопределить в нем методы рисования. Дальше можно либо зарегистрировать его (см. [пример создания и регистрации](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/gui_int.html#lnf)), или установить на нужный компонент руками.

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI( new MetalScrollBarUI() {
    @Override
    protected void paintThumb( Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle tb ) {
        g.setColor( Color.GREEN );
        if ( scrollbar.getOrientation() == JScrollBar.VERTICAL ) {
          g.fillRect( tb.x, tb.y, tb.width, tb.height );
        } else {
          g.fillRect( tb.x, tb.y, tb.width, tb.height );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle tb) {
        g.setColor( Color.RED );
        g.fillRect(tb.x, tb.y, tb.width, tb.height);
    }
});
```

Будет красная полоса прокрутки с зеленым ползунком.